# ruby - rails: add key val pair to serialized hash in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to rails and have the following problem:
I have an array of serialized hashes stored in a database. Now I want to extend the hash data with a new key-value pair (calculated from stored data), e.g. like this in Ruby:

Data stored database:

```
coordinates = Array.new

c1 = Hash.new('x' => x1, 'y' => y1)
c2 = Hash.new('x' => x2, 'y' => y2)
c3 = Hash.new('x' => x3, 'y' => y3)
coordinates << c1 << c2 << c3
```

Extending data:

```
coordinates.each_with_index do |c, i|
  c['z'] = c['x'] + c['y']
```

Representation in the database looks like:

```
"coordinates_table": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "coordinates": [
      { "x": 1.0, "y": 0.5 },
      { "x": 0.5, "y": 0.4 }
    ],
    "created_at": "2015-11-22T00:18:38.592Z",
    "updated_at": "2015-11-22T00:18:38.592Z"
  }
]
```

This is the original migration:

```
class CreateCoordinates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change        
    create_table :coordinates do |t|
      t.text :coordinates_param

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :coordinates, :id
  end
end
```

and Coordinate class:

```
class Coordinate < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :coordinates_param
end
```

Since I do not intend to change the input data, but only extend the data stored in the database, I figured the best way to realize this was a migration, but I did not find any way to access single Hash objects stored in my table in the generated migration model.

Is there any possibility to do this in rails, or do I have to provide a separate extension class where I could store the new data?

Comment: How have you saved Hash in Database? Can you share the table structure and a sample value stored in that table?

Comment: @FabianPöschl You may answer your own question, and then after a time, give it the checkmark.  This will help anyone else who has the same problem.